# Unable to reference a sub-flow present in another file mule 4

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am trying to reference a flow/sub-flow from one file to another in mule 4 but keep getting the error "flow-ref at test.xml:76 is pointing to genericFlow which does not exist"...during deployment.... even though the anypoint studio is able to find it...

Edit:
I have been able to solve this problem.
I found that the flow I was referring had a problem due to which it was not getting initiated or something....The problem was that I was using && instead of "and" as relative operator....after fixing that it worked fine....

Comment: Please add the complete error message, the flow-ref XML snippet, the sub-flow definition, and in what file it is located. Is it in another XML of the same application? Or in a jar file?

Answer (score 0):

The flow ref name shouldn't include the name of the file, once the file is included into the `mule-artifact.json` in the `"configs"` array property. You should reference the `sub-flow` by doing `<flow-ref name="{nameofthesubflowontheotherfile}">`

**Take in mind that you cannot have flows or subflows with the same name**